# Using a list to query MongoDB

Tags: python, arrays, mongodb, list, pymongo

I'm using a list to keep track of products. I want to use this list to query MongoDB without using a for loop.

I'm using Python 3 and Pymongo.

```
product_list = [product1, product2, product3]

cursor = db.collection.find({'product_id': product_list})
```

I could create a for loop, but is there a way to query MongoDB using a list or array from Python?

Edit: I want to return results each time a product in the product_list is found.

Comment: What is the condition you want?

Comment: I want to return results for each product. I'll update your question in the post.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @D. SM pointed out, I can use the $IN operator found here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/

Just so others can see the Python syntax that worked for me:

```
product_list = [product1, product2, product3]

cursor = db.collection.find({'product_id': {'$in': product_list}})
```

The in$ must be in quotes.